# When is the cdf of a (multivariate) random variable everywhere differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let a random variable $X=(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n): \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$ defined on some background background space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be given.

Which properties of the distribution $X(P)$ are necessary and sufficient to conclude that the associated cdf $F_X: \mathbb{R}^n \to [0,1]$ is differentiable $\textit{everywhere}$?

By my understanding, it is always the case that $F_X$ is cyclically monotone, hence always almost everywhere differentiable. I want more.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: I suspect any definition would in effect be circular, such as admitting a density or absolute continuity.  What would you say about the $n=1$ case?

Comment: Even when $n=1$, abs. cont. is not enough (consider e.g. the uniform distribution). Perhaps something like abs. cont. + full support would be sufficient, but those are strict requirements.

Comment: If you are worried about cases where the derivative is arbitrary at some points, you seem to be looking for a continuous density: $6x(1-x)$ on $[0,1]$ and $0$ elsewhere would do, so there are cases without full support.  Meanwhile a density of $\frac12 e^{-x}$ on $[0,\infty)$ and $e^{2x}$ on $(-\infty,0)$ would not do because of what happens at $x=0$, suggesting absolute continuity and full support would not be sufficient.

Comment: @Henry Thank you for illuminating response. I get that abs. cont. + continuous density imply everywhere differentiability of the CDF. Do you know if these properties are necessary as well? Are you familiar with a distribution which is not abs. cont. but whose CDF is everywhere differentiable?